# Internet Explorer 8 back-to-back divs CSS issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

The following layout works fine in every browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera), except Internet Explorer 8:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="divMain" class="CMain">
            <div id="divL" class="CLeft">
            </div>
            <div id="divR" class="CRight">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.CMain {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 75%;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 550px;
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.CLeft {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50%;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 450px;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 550px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.CRight{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 450px;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The two inner divs are supposed to be back-to-back in the center of the main div, and they clearly are in every browser except IE8. In IE8, the left div goes to the left side, not in the center.

Am I doing something wrong? ( please don't suggest removing min/max-width/height constraints, they are needed ). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a fiddle with this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/fNtJU/

imageshack screenshot link ie8: http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/3838/ie8g.jpg

Comment: Looks the same for IE8 (with and without compat view) and Chrome to me.

Comment: not true, maybe you tried it in jsfiddle where the window is too small to see, in chrome and firefox etc the two divs are back-to-back in ie8 there is a space between them

Comment: here is a screenshot: http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/3838/ie8g.jpg

Comment: It's probably due to `max-width`...

Comment: Sure it does... width is 49% of the container with a min of 200px and a max of 450px. If 49% of the container is more than 450px, the div will only be 450px.

Comment: it doesn't make sense because the right div stands correctly positioned, only the left one moves to the left.

so what's the problem if the div is only 450px? that's the purpose of max-width.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a width on the main container? for example, width: 90%; and lose the left:20px;/right:20px;. I don't think the child containers can calculate a position when the parent doesn't have an explicit width specified, even with max-width. I can't test on ie8 currently though.

Comment: Oops, I meant for this answer to be a comment.

Comment: if the child containers can't calculate it, then why the problem occurs only with the left div and not the right one? The right div is exactly in the center, where it should, but not the left one.